# Assetic: Writer do not generate all files on debug mode

Tags: assetic

I'm trying to connect assetic with Twig (on Zend). It seems to work ok for debug=false, but I cannot understand what it does for development.

Basically, when calling this:

```
{% javascripts 'static/js/*.js' %}
    <p>{{asset_url}}</p>
{% endjavascripts %}
```

it outputs a list of generated javascript file names (which is nice):

```
js/d19cc07_part_1_jquery-1.7.2.min_6.js
js/d19cc07_part_1_jquery.cookie_7.js
js/d19cc07_part_1_jquery.jeditable.mini_8.js
```

but these files are not generated by writter (it only generates js/d19cc07.js). For debug=false it outputs just one file name and also renders it correctly.

So what am I missing here?

Here's how I initialize it:

```
    //Assetic
    $factory = new \Assetic\Factory\AssetFactory(APP_BASE_PATH . '/public/');
    $factory->setDebug(true);
    $am = new \Assetic\Factory\LazyAssetManager($factory);

    //enable loading assets from twig templates
    $loader = new \Twig_Loader_Filesystem(array());
    $loader->addPath(APP_BASE_PATH.'/application/templates/default');

    //Init twig
    $twig = new \Twig_Environment($loader);
    $twig->addExtension(new \Assetic\Extension\Twig\AsseticExtension($factory));

    $am->setLoader('twig', new \Assetic\Extension\Twig\TwigFormulaLoader($twig));


    $templates = array('/index/index.html'); //An array containing full paths to my templates

    foreach ($templates as $template) {
        $resource = new \Assetic\Extension\Twig\TwigResource($loader, $template);

        $am->addResource($resource, 'twig');
    }

    //Writer
    $writer = new \Assetic\AssetWriter(APP_BASE_PATH . '/public/static/assetic');
    $writer->writeManagerAssets($am);

    echo $twig->render('index/index.html');
```

Comment: Im having the exact same problem. I don't understand how this works, since the writer does not write those "part1" files. I think Symfony handles this through a controller, but that doesn't seem right to me. And also, it is supposed to work without Symfony so... I dont know whats the purpose of this behavior. Anyone can throw some light on this?

Comment: I managed to connect using "DumpCommand" from Symfony, that required just using few components for console (which I used anyway for doctrine). That command was quite useful for me, so  I didn't dig deeper on how the actual problem was solved. If you don't want to connect symfony, just check how they did it here https://github.com/symfony/AsseticBundle/blob/master/Command/DumpCommand.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up connecting Symfony console to my Zend project and slightly adopting DumpCommand from assetic to make this work (by passing my version of DI containter with assigned AsseticManager).